# Storage permission dined in Android Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, storage

My app have a problem with STORAGE permission in `Android version: 13`, it returns false always and don't show allow permission popup when I use the following line:

`await Permission.storage.request().isGranted`

I use:

`permission_handler: ^10.2.0`

`Flutter version: 3.3.10`

My permissions in AndroidManifest.xml are here:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
   
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:maxSdkVersion` to 33

https://apilevels.com/

Comment: in which file do you mean? thanks

Comment: In the AndroidManifest behind your permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I added it, but still don't work when I try to access files and folders in the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should not request READ and or WRITE external storage permission on an Android 13 device.

Only the READ_MEDIA_XXXC permissions.

Comment: But what if the device has Android version < 13?

Comment: Then ask them..

Comment: What you mean with "Ask them" ?

Comment: Request them....

Comment: Do you mean that "READ and or WRITE external storage permission" should be removed from AndroidManifest.xml and use "READ_MEDIA_XXXC permissions" instead?

Comment: No i did not mean that. How could you ever think so? Requesting is at runtime. Leave all in your manifest. In manifest it us 'uses'. Not 'request'.